# Unable to add a new Fabric peer as an anchor peer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have followed the [Adding a new Org to a Channel](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/channel_update_tutorial.html) tutorial for Fabric V1.3. What I have discovered is that it is not possible to update the new peer as an anchor peer, because the `Org3MSPAnchors.tx` is not generated in the `channel_artifacts` folder during this procedure.

And it seems that the only way to generate an `Org3MSPAnchors.tx` would be to extend the profile in `configtx.yaml` - which seems to me to be antithetical to the idea of adding a new organisation (as `configtx.yaml` defines the genesis block, and by definition, I do not know about **new** organisations when I define the genesis block).

Do I misunderstand how to make a peer and anchor peer? Can somebody explain what should happen after the [Adding a new Org to a Channel](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/channel_update_tutorial.html) tutorial?